# Black screen with blinking cursor after dual boot install 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my toshiba laptop along side Windows 7.
When the menu comes up to choose which OS to boot into, I can easily boot into Windows 7.
I cannot successfully boot into Ubuntu. All I get is a blinking cursor on a black/purple screen. 
I attempted the nomodeset trick, which was a bit more successful. I got a screen with a lot of code, but then it stopped with a blinking cursor at the bottom and wouldn't load anymore.

As a last resort, would returning my laptop to factory settings get rid of linux and the partitions made to the drive? I already did this to my laptop when it was just windows, which is why I thought I might as well try to add Ubuntu. But it's a lengthy process, and if it won't get rid of the partitions and ubuntu, I won't bother.

I appreciate any help
~many thanks

Comment: Which graphic card are you using? I am experiencing similar problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and a nvidia card (although it is not linked to dual boot)

Answer (score 0):

To return your settings is very easy you could do this for example: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I strongly recommend you try booting back up with the installation media and select "Try ubuntu" Then download and run a program called boot-repair

If that fails I strongly recommend reinstalling ubuntu and even verifying the .iso sha1sum or md5 sum. Ubuntu should run on your computer without problem.

**One time I had your problem and could not boot into linux because the hard drive that linux was on was not working properly**

Comment: I downloaded and ran boot repair, but it did not fix the issue. The address they gave me was http://paste.ubuntu.com/7481108/

Comment: Also, to reinstall it, can I simply boot from a flash drive and install over Ubuntu? Would you recommend trying to use 12.04 instead of 14.04?

Comment: Before giving up I would try 12.04 yes, to reinstall yes simply boot back into the flash drive, but instead of clicking next next next. when you get to the install part click advanced and delete /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 that is where you have ubuntu installed now. then click the deleted/unalocated partition and select change and and set the size to however much memory you have and select partition type primary and file system swap (if you have ALOT of memory dont even make a swap) then select the deleted/unalocated space and create new primary partition set mount path to / and set it to ext4

Comment: make sure that on the bottom it reads that grub is being isntalled to /dev/sda

Also if thats confusing i think (but am not sure) that you can just delete/format your /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 and then power down and boot back into your flash and next next next. Also i read your paste file and from what I know it looks fine :( are you installing 64bit ubuntu or 32bit? it might matter?

Comment: You can click "try ubuntu" on your installation medium right?

Comment: I'm installing 64 bit, but that is correct for my computer. im currently downloading the 12.04 iso, and ill try to do what you said. thank you so muchforthe help! ill report back on if it works (here's hoping!)